# Call a Row By Clicking A Button MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating an online exam. My layout is to show one question at a time and below it is the multiple choice. At the bottom of the multiple choice is a 'Next' button that when click will show the next question.

The questions and multiple choice are stored in a database.

The problem is, the next button functions, but it redirects me to another page. When all I want is to hide the previous question and show the next question when the next is clicked.

This is my code:
**db**

```
CREATE TABLE `english` (
  `E_QueID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Question` text NOT NULL,
  `A` text NOT NULL,
  `B` text NOT NULL,
  `C` text NOT NULL,
  `D` text NOT NULL,
  `E` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**html**

```
    <div class="col-sm-8 bt-query">
        <br>
        <h4><left>Question 1</left>&nbsp;<right><div class="timer" data-seconds-left="20"></div></right></h4>
        <br>
        <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM english ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if (!$result) { // add this check.
                    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
                }

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['Question']. "<br />";
                echo $row['A']. "<br />";
                echo $row['B']. "<br />";
                echo $row['C']. "<br />";
                echo $row['D']. "<br />";
                echo $row['E']. "<br />";
                }
        ?>
        <br>
        <form action="englishq.php" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
        </form>
    </div>
```

**englishq.php**

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db = 'questions';

//databse connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$user", "$password", "$db")or die(mysqli_error());
    if(isset($_GET['next'])){

        $query="SELECT * FROM english ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (!$result) { // add this check.
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
         }

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['Question']. "<br />";
            echo $row['A']. "<br />";
            echo $row['B']. "<br />";
            echo $row['C']. "<br />";
            echo $row['D']. "<br />";
            echo $row['E']. "<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: this question was already asked a couple of hours ago, I will search for the duplicate

Comment: You could combine both php scripts and let the `action` attribute of the `form` empty. It will send the data to the same script back. Where are the `<input type="radio">` elements in your code? Add some within the `<form></from>`

Comment: @davejal - I don't think it is a real "duplicate", since obviously this code has  been developed based on the last more general question by the PO. Now she ran into a more specific problem, she is currently trying to solve. It's a step by step learning process, asking for advice in some stages.

Comment: Yes I found the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/37230884/3664960), but it doesn't have an answer or upvote (so I can't flag it as duplicate). Something's telling me this is homework.

Comment: @davejal - Ok, the question you've linked looks a bit more duplicat than the one I've found. There actually *is* one answer, so we can't ask to delete the other one instead. But the current question is better outworked and could get the potential to be a good question. There is running code with a misbehavior, a problem and an aim.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the form's action parameter blank, so the form will submit back to the current page.  Then use PHP to read the last question submitted and load the next one to display it to the user.  You could use a hidden input field to keep track of which question was submitted.

Form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="question_number" value="<?php echo $mynumber; ?>" />
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="A." /><?php echo $answerA; ?> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="B." /><?php echo $answerB; ?> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="C." /><?php echo $answerC; ?> <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="D." /><?php echo $answerD; ?> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['question_number']))
{
    // Record the last answer
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_answer_table (answer_field) VALUES (':answer')");
    $stmt->bindParams(':answer', $_POST['answer']);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Load the next question
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE question_id = :questionid");
    $stmt_>bindParams(':questionid',$_POST['question_number']+1);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if a `$_POST` contains an answer. If yes, check if it is correct. Give a feedback. On incorrect answer you might ask the same question again, else generate a new random id.

Place a form around the page content, that sends the data back to the same script.

```
<form action="" type="post">
```

Give the client the question id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="qid" value="<?php echo $row['E_QueID';?>">
```

Inside the loop over the data table generate some radio buttons

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="ansA" name="answer" value="A">
  <label for="ansA"><?php echo $row['A'];?></label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="ansB" name="answer" value="B">
  <label for="ansB"><?php echo $row['B'];?></label>
</div>
```

Add a submit button and close the form tag.